# Interfacing key-pad with arduino with 7 segment display

Tags: arduino-mega, keyboard, 7-segment

I have the following components:

- Arduino Mega
- 7-segment display
- 12-digit key-pad

For my project, I would like to display on the 7-segment display the number that the user presses on the keypad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: please note that you have to fill in the last function in order to get an int value from your keypad. The 7-segments part of the code should be fine.

```
const int segment[7] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; //pins for each segment

const int nums[10][7] = //declaring array
{
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,0}, //0
  {0,1,1,0,0,0,0}, //1
  {1,1,0,1,0,0,1}, //2
  {1,1,1,1,0,0,1}, //3
  {0,1,1,0,0,1,1}, //4
  {1,0,1,1,0,1,1}, //5
  {1,0,1,1,1,1,1}, //6
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0}, //7
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, //8
  {1,1,1,0,0,1,1}  //9
};

void setup() {
  for(int i=2; i<=8; i++) //shorcut for declaring a buch of pin modes
  {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}

//=======================================================================

void loop() {
  number(keypadInput);
}

//=======================================================================

void number(int num) //num is the number to display
{
  for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(segment[i], nums[num][i]);
  }
}

int (keypadInput)
{
  //code for getting the input of your keypad
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will definitely add this code once I get my keypad.  Thanks a lot.